# Tomcat "Connection Reset" SSL error

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, https

I have a java application that is an iframe in a separate application. The iframe is javascript that sends requests to a Java servlet that handles the requests and such.
The issue is when I'm trying to setup HTTPS support, I cannot get the application to work. When loading the application, I get a "Connection Reset" error from Mozilla before the page even loads.

Here are my settings:
Web.xml w/ security contraint:

```
    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>GeoLocationMappingTest</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <user-data-constraint>
            <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
```

Server XML:

```
<Connector  port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" SSLEnabled="true"
               maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" keystoreFile="conf/.ms_server_keystore.CA_NEW"
                keystorePass="*****"/>
    <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
        <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />.
        <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
                   connectionTimeout="20000"
                   redirectPort="8443" />
```

I don't get any errors on catalina.out nor on the console output for the application (which is directed to catalina.out)

Comment: Did you create a key-store and a self-signed certificate, and more importantly installed them ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why, but reinstalling Tomcat on the Centos 5 box seemed to fix the issue. Past that, I copied and pasted the same info I had from my previous installation and everything worked. Very strange.